# What is the best way for custom spacing between rows in material-ui grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, grid-system, mui

what is the best way to have a spacing between certain rows within a grid in material-ui?

For example, given the following grid with `spacing={0}`.

```
GridContainer
row1    GridItem GridItem
row2    GridItem GridItem
row3    GridItem GridItem
row4    GridItem GridItem
```

The goal is to have the same grid with spacing of 0, but with custom spacing between rows 2 and 3

```
GridContainer
row1    GridItem GridItem
row2    GridItem GridItem

row3    GridItem GridItem
row4    GridItem GridItem
```

I tried to put `mt={2)` to GridItems in the 3rd row but it did not work. I achieved the behaviour with a custom class passed via the className attribute, though I am not sure if this is the best way to go.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid container layout={"row"} spacing={10} >
   <Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
      <div style={{height: "100%", paddingTop: 5}}>add your component here</div>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I assume its better via className because you can then omit the div-wrapper

Comment: Yes that's possible too, set className and style it in your css

Comment: That's what I am doing now but it seems there should be a "nicer" solution which I am not aware of, and thus reason for this question

Comment: yep, we have to wait for the others.